# How do I map a different type to a char field in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a custom class that has an implicit conversion with string. I'm using POCO classes in c# with EF6.0 and I'd like to be able to declare a property like this:

```
[Column("TABLE_COLUMN_NAME", TypeName = "char")]
public virtual CustomClass ClassColumnName { get; set; }
```

Then have entity framework just assign the value taking advantage of the implicit conversion. However when I try to run this code I get an error like `Error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments`. `CustomClass` has an implicit conversion operator setup for both going to and coming from string but it appears that EF wants to treat the whole type as if it were a table and fails the mapping. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I eliminate Error 3002?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835928/how-do-i-eliminate-error-3002)

Comment: His issue is with a column being misidentified as a primary key. That is not the case here.